# UINavigationControllerDelegate breaks pushViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a view controller where I implement UIImagePickerDelegate and UINavigationControllerDelegate inorder to get an image either from the gallery, or the camera. After picking the image I want to navigate to another view controller. However running the code to push is not working. I know the UINavigationController is not nil, and if I remove the UINavigationControllerDelegate and push it works. What the heck is going on?

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animation: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... found it. I wasn't dismissing the ImagePicker before trying to navigate away.